# Internship Year mistake on resume

Tags: internship, background-check

I recently received a summer internship offer with a company, and am now in the background check phase. I noticed that I accidentally listed my previous internship start and end date as March 2014 - May 2014 instead of March 2015 - May 2015, that is, I accidentally listed the year one year prior to when I started. The months, job title and company are all accurate. What do you think I should do? Should I contact the HR and tell her I made this mistake? Or wait for the results of the background check to come back?

Comment: Call them and say - it's a really minor mistake, imo.

Comment: Proof read important documents in future, a mistake on a resume is a red flag to an employer for many reasons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no real harm in dropping HR a quick line to inform them of the typo - it's an easy enough mistake to make and I think that it's much more likely to be seen that way if you provide that correction unprompted rather than in response to the descrepency coming up as a result of the background check.